# How to redirect CURL output to file and as bash function parameter

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

How can I make curl output to `$LOG` and as a second parameter for the `json_extract` function.

`json_extract` is a function that takes two args. The 'key' and a json string (the output of CURL)

```
param=$(json_extract $jsonkey "$(curl -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
    -X POST --data "$data" $url >> $LOG )")
```

When I remove the redirect to `$LOG` CURL output is passed as an argument for `json_extract`.

Comment: what do you mean by "and as a $2 parameter for the json_extract function"?   and by "...it works as a parameter?" - what is the "it" you're referring to?  and what does "it works" actually mean? there seems to be a lot of context missing from this question.

Comment: @cas I updated the question.

Comment: if i'm reading the updated Q correctly, why not run something like: `response="$(curl .....)"; echo "$response" >> "$LOG"; param=$(json_extract "$jsonkey" "$response")`?   i.e. if you want to use the output of a command multiple times, store it in a variable and use the variable wherever it is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use the output of a single command more than once.  In that case, you need to store it in a variable, and then use that variable wherever needed.  e.g. try something like this:

```
response="$(curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
  -X POST --data "$data" "$url")"

echo "$response" >> "$LOG"
param=$(json_extract "$jsonkey" "$response")
```

---

Another alternative is to use `tee`, which sends a command's output to a file as well as to stdout.  For example:

```
param=$(json_extract "$jsonkey" "$(curl -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
    -X POST --data "$data" "$url" | tee -a "$LOG" )")
```

Personally, I find that using a variable like "$response" leads to more readable and understandable code.   Especially when it lets you split very long, complicated one-liners into multiple shorter, easily-understood lines.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! I used a variable. Like you said, it's more readable